# .htaccess file not working after once

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't know much about .htaccess and .htpasswd, but somehow i managed to protect my webpage. But i don't know if it is possible to .htaccess to ask for username and password every time I reload my webpage but instead it only ask for user and pass. only once after i update new user and pass. Please suggest me something because i want my webpage to ask for user and pass every time i reload.

here is my .htaccess file

```
AuthUserFile /home/a8785398/public_html/.htpasswd

AuthName "admin"

AuthType Basic

<Files "admin.php">

  require valid-user

</Files>
```

here is my .htpasswd file

```
admin:$apr1$d1LO3XVK$on0bPEdEUuQXzGmuRxoht.
```

Comment: You shouldn't show your password hash in here. Someone could Bruteforce it and get your real password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
AuthName "admin"
AuthUserFile /home/a8785398/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

Comment: Thanks You for replying but sorry it not working either. It also ask for username and pass only once but i want it to popup at every reload.

Comment: If you want that, you'd better use another option than .htaccess, read more: http://www.aota.net/forums/showthread.php?t=20263.

Comment: Thankyou- i think i should look out for another security like php script that i have tried before but there also a problem. It was 
my php script goes smthng like this:
<?php
user=
pass=
if {echo my webpage}
plzz enter correct
?>
but it is not loading webpage as contains php script too and it returns error instead of full page.
plzz help if yiu have any idea

Comment: That seems more like another new question. Please mark my answer as the solution if it helped you.